# What Android is blue screen?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I make a game in Unity, and export it for android studio.
I use emulator for launch the game, Pixel 1 - SDK 24.

After press run, game launched and screen gets blue screen. Logo unity don't show. But music play, and when I touch game work.

When a build APK from android studio, and install on device, I get error, apk damaged.

When I build directly from unity and install on device game work, but on emulator is blue screen.

EDITED: On emulator I install Unity remote, and it get blue screen ;(

SOLUTION: Update your API in android studio >=26

Comment: Please check on another phone, this looks more like an SD card problem than Unity3D problem

Comment: @zambari If I create a new application in android studio, then everything compiles fine